# MySQL Regexp for Finding a CSV number

Tags: mysql, regex

How do you find a number (e.g., "8") in a CSV string in a MySQL field without finding numbers that contain that number (e.g., "18" or "81")?

For example:

1. csvString1 in `somecolumn` = `8,14,18`
2. csvString2 in `somecolumn` = `4,5,8,13`
3. csvString2 in `somecolumn` = `18,81,82,88`

I need to have #1 and #2 come up `true` and #3 come up `false`.  How do I do that

`SELECT *
FROM sometable
WHERE somecolumn REGEXP '(what here?)';`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `find_in_set`

```
select find_in_set('8', '18,81,82,88');
--> zero

select find_in_set('8', '8,14,18');
--> 1

select find_in_set('8', '4,5,8,13');
--> 3
```

So,

```
select * from your_table
where find_in_set('8', your_col)<>0;
```

**PS:** normalize your data to avoid future problem

Comment: same as not equal (not smaller than, and not greater than)